# How do I add free songs to Google Music after already registering?

Tags: google-play-music

When creating a new Google Music account, they suggest some free songs for you to add to the library. I've added some free songs to the library, but not all of them. Now I would like to add some more. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the free songs you're talking about from [Magnifier](http://magnifier.blogspot.com/).

> Visit the [Magnifier](http://magnifier.blogspot.com/) home page and the [Free Song Archive](http://magnifier.blogspot.com/p/free-song-archive.html) to access all of the available free music.
>
> 1. Select **'Add free music'**.
> 2. Log in to Music Beta (if you're not already logged in).
> 3. Click the **'Listen Now'** button that appears, and it will take you directly to the **'Free songs'** playlist in Music Beta.

From the [help page](http://www.google.com/support/music/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1633629&topic=1100183).

Note that you can't add a specific playlist, artist, or track.

Comment: Thanks, but I was not talking about adding music from my computer. When creating a Google Music account for the first time, they let you add to the library sets of free songs (each set consists of about 100 songs). I've added some of the sets when creating the account. Now I would like to add sets I haven't added.

Comment: You can add it from Magnifier. See the last part of my reply.

Comment: Thanks. You've solved my problem. I've edited your answer and eliminated details which aren't relevant to what I'm asking. Please review and approve my edit.